# When to use ordinary, balanced, antithetic, or permutation resampling for bootstrap?

Tags: r, sampling, bootstrap, simulation, resampling

I am using [boot](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/boot/boot.pdf) and would appreciate any explanation as to when using each of these resampling methods would be recommended in practice.

I have come across [Do](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00949659208811373) who says that:

> Simulation results reveal that balanced resampling provide better
>   efficiencies in most cases; however, antithetic resampling is superior
>   in estimating bias of the median.

Still, it is not clear to me when either of these would be more advisable than "ordinary" (the default in boot), or "permutation."

Example of applicable scenarios would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance for any help.